# Как заставить две функции работать одновременно?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, асинхронность, asyncio

Есть две функции flud и flud_to_phantom:

```
async def flud(account....):
    for account in account_list:
        try:
            app = Client(name=account[1:])

            async def connect_to_main():
                async with app:
                    await app.join_chat(chat_id=chat_link)
                    await app.stop()
            app.run(connect_to_main())
        except UserAlreadyParticipant:
            print('акаунт уже в группе')
        print('Успешно')

    while True:
        app_flud = Client(name=account)
        text = choice(messages)

        async def in_flud():
            async with app_flud:
                await app_flud.send_message(chat_id=chat.id, text=text)
                await app_flud.stop()
        app_flud.run(in_flud())
        acc_n = counter(acc_n, account_list)
        print(f'аккаунт {acc_n}/{len(account_list)} отправил сообщение')
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)


async def flud_to_phantom(new...):
    if is_phantom:
        while True:
            app = Client(name=account)
            text = choice(messages)     
            async def ph_flud():
                async with app:
                    await app.send_message(chat_id=new_chat.id, text=text)
                    await app.stop()

            app.run(ph_flud())
            await asyncio.sleep(phantom_delay)
```

Никак не могу понять как заставить их работать одновременно, мучаюсь уже второй день.
Последнее что я пробовал это запускать их через отдельную функцию, но ничего не помогает(

```
async def runner(ne...):
    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(flud(acco...))
    task_2 = asyncio.create_task(flud_to_phantom(new_c...))
    await asyncio.gather(task_1, task_2)
```

Практически всегда выскакивает вот такая ошибка:

```
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\main.py", line 277, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\...\main.py", line 265, in main
    loop.run_until_complete(runner(new...
  File "C:\Users\...\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\...\main.py", line 218, in runner
    await asyncio.gather(task_1, task_2)
  File "C:\Users\...\main.py", line 98, in flud
    app.run(connect_to_main())
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\utilities\run.py", line 85, in run
    run(idle())
  File "C:\Users\...\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 622, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "C:\Users...\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 582, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'idle' was never awaited
```

у меня больше не осталось идеи, что может мне помочь.

Comment: Попробуйте тогда переписать код под запуск в потоках.

Comment: @Gruvi через потоки тоже ошибка: RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1 (flud)'.
raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2 (flud_to_phantom)

Comment: У вас ошибка вылетает на строке `asyncio.create_task(app.run(await connect_to_main()))` в функции `fluid`, но в приведенном коде в функции `fluid` ее нет. Добавьте в вопрос именно тот код, на которому у вас возникает ошибка.

Comment: да, извиняюсь, но даже если оставить просто app.run(connect_to_main()) как в примере, то будет точнно такая же ошибка

Comment: Извинения не нужны, нужно вопрос так, чтобы по тексту ошибки можно было отследить причину возникновения в коде, и понять как исправить. Сейчас это невозможно, т.к. ошибка не соответствует коду.

Comment: * исправить вопрос

Answer (score 0):

модуль threading поможет

```
import threading
threading.Thread(target=flud).start() #паралельная функция
flud_to_phantom() #главная функция
```

а если хотите добавить агрументы в функцию то после target=flud вставьте код `, args=((аргумент1, аргумент 2),)`

Comment: Не нужно мешать асинхронность с многопоточностью )

Comment: RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1 (flud)'.
raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'